# Pycharm pyenv picks up wrong python library: how to fix?

Tags: python, pycharm, python-venv

***tldr;***

"Python from Pycharm" does not use the 'virtual environment version of  "configparser"'.  How do i fix?

**Apologia**

I'm new to python so not adept at virtual environment nuances and tweaks.

**Details**

Here is the situation:

- I've worked periodically on long running project and have successfully ran/debugged the app in Pycharm in the past few months
- After I upgraded my mac/brew from 3.6.4 to 3.7, Pycharm debugging failed...specifically a library method "configparser.py"  (FWIW, the 3.7 configparser chokes on None value, whereas the 3.6.4. version allowed None.)
- As "this used to work, but now fails and I haven't touched any project code", I assumed the issue lay with 3.6.4 to 3.7 upgrade.
- I set up, via the command line, a virtual environment using python 3.6.4 ; the application runs successfully from the command line.
- However, I cannot get Pycharm-with-virtual-environments to use the '3.6.4' version of configparser.py. The console logs always shows a failue in the 3.7.0 version of configparser
- I have tried both "pointing pycharm to my 3.6.4 virtual environment" and "creating a fresh virtual enviornment" in pycharm. No luck.

**Pycharm Console**

Python console shows:

```
File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/configparser.py", line 1225, in __init__
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

**Question:**

- How do I get pycharm to use the config
- Why does Pycharm work differently than python from the command line?

Comment: DId you set the interpreter in the Pycharm project settings to the one in the virtualenv?

Comment: Yes. I set the pycharm preference Project Interpretor to ~/.pyvenv/versions/myvenv (i.e where 'myvenv' is the correctd virtual env)

Comment: same here seems pycharm pick up a wrong lib root for virtualenv created by pyenv